# Google Hangouts window invisible

Tags: windows-10, google-hangouts

I am currently running **Windows 10** and using Chrome. I have a Dell laptop and a second monitor running both as extended windows.

When I receive a message from **google hangouts** I can see the notification pop up but can not find the window. I have tried to close and open hangouts, reboot and minimize all of the windows.  Is there a way I can force the window to be visible?

When I ran a Mac OS I used the "zoom" command to find these hidden/invisible windows but not sure what to do in Windows 10.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can try two things.

Click on the Hangouts window icon in your taskbar.  Then try Windows Key + Left or Right arrow (keep pressing them to continue moving the window).  This may move the window to the left or right side of your screen, then you can drag it where you want.

You can also try this.  Click on the Hangouts icon in your taskbar.  Press Alt + Spacebar, then hit M, then click any arrow key direction, then move the mouse.  The window should be attached to your cursor and you can place it where you like.

Try and practice these on visible windows first.

Comment: Thanks! The Alt+Spacebar worked with the move command. The other two did not.

Comment: This brings it back once, but it happens every time I close the Hangouts window and reopen it.  Is there no way to stop it from opening "offscreen" in the first place?

Answer (score 3):

The answer from @natewin did not work.

However, <kbd>Alt + Spacebar</kbd> → <kbd>x</kbd> maximized the Hangouts screen into a viewable area,  allowing me to drag it to center, resize, then re-place onto my desktop area.

Comment: This worked for me after trying 2-3 times.

Comment: Another option you can try is to use Shift+Right-Mouse on the Hangouts Taskbar icon. This should give you all contextual options for manipulating a container Window, e.g. Size, Movement, etc.

Answer (score -1):

I have a MS Surface Book with two identical ViewSonic external monitors and this happens with Google Hangouts at least 2-3 times per month. Definitely seems like a flaw in the programming to me.

Neither the 'Windows Key + Left Arrow/Right Arrow' or the 'Alt + Spacebar, then hit M, then click arrow key any direction, then move mouse' solutions suggested worked for me. However, what did work was a variation of the second method.

What worked for me was clicking on the Hangouts icon, pressing Alt + Spacebar, then pressing M, then clicking the 'Maximize' option. Hangouts immediately appeared back on my primary monitor (SurfaceBook). Hope this helps someone else.